# How to get date using 3 date components with varied data types

Tags: python

I have three variables:

```py
week_no = 2
day = 'Fri'
year = 2021
```

I need to locate the date by using these variables and output as a `datetime.date` object.

Thanks.

Comment: Wouldn't you also need a particular year to get the actual date?

Comment: I'm not sure you can get a date from those. The weeks will start on a different date each year. It's also worth noting that there are different definitions of when week 1 is within a year, with some starting on very surprising dates.

Comment: Both correct, I've edited my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following code:

```
datetime.datetime.strptime(f'{week_no} {day} {year}', '%U %a %Y')
```

Return following result:

```
datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 15, 0, 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to use [datetime.date.fromisocalendar](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.fromisocalendar), though this is only available in Python 3.8+.

> Return a date corresponding to the ISO calendar date specified by year, week and day. This is the inverse of the function date.isocalendar().

```
date.fromisocalendar(year, week, day)
```

The day is specified as an integer between 1 and 7.

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.date.fromisocalendar(2021, 2, 5)
datetime.date(2021, 1, 15)
```

Comment: Note that this will require Python 3.8